# Legend on bottom with highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highcharts to draw some charts. I use the basic line plot like this:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time

How can I display the legend under the chart area instead of at the right?

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-percent

Thx

Comment: api highcharts -> [legend align](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.align)

Comment: You can not put it under the chart, i mean, i failed to do that

Comment: sorry,you need [verticalAlign](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.verticalAlign) to be 'bottom'.

Comment: how about using marginBottom? like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XwJfn/)?

Comment: @BojanKovacevic Perfect, write an answer and i validate it !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

marginBottom can be used to put legend on bottom of chart. You can still use legend property to move legend for example in the middle or right(i used center).

```
 chart: {
        marginBottom: 100
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
```

Possible solution: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XwJfn/)

Answer (score 6):

Having the legend under the chart is the default, so you can omit the `legend` propery entirely. Bear in mind that to make this look nice, you'll have to add a little to the bottom margin, otherwise the chart and the legend will overlap.

```
chart: {
    type: 'line',
    marginRight: 130,
    marginBottom: 70 // Increase this to 70 or so
},
// Remove the legend property completely
```

[Here's a demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/59YRJ/).